I'm flying from U.S. to London to Prague. When do I clear customs?
I'm going to fly from Philadelphia to London to Prague.  When will I go through customs - In London or in Prague?

Are you self-transferring in London or is this booked as one journey (one PNR)? Which London airport and which airline(s)?

Put your exact details in here: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa . This depends very much on how the ticket was booked and which airport you are using. You WILL go through customs in Prague no matter what but you MAY also go through it in London depending on your specific details.

If your two flights are on a single ticket and you don’t change airports in London, then the only entry checks (passport control for you and customs for your goods) will happen in Prague, which will be your point of entry into the Schengen Area (for you) and the EU common market (for your goods).
If for any reason you need to pass border control in the UK (self-transfer or change of airport for instance), you will go through those checks in London and then again in Prague (the UK has never been part of the Schengen Area and is no longer an EU member, so they act independently).

Some London airports do not allow for direct transfer, I think Gatwick is one that has intercontinetal flights but no international transfers without entering the country.

Thanks. The flight is into LHR and there is no airport change there - just a 2-hour layover. The full trip is booked on one ticket.
